# UWP App GpioController.GetDefault() always returns null

Tags: c#, uwp, gpio

What can be the reason that in my App `GpioController.GetDefault()` always returns null? The app is running on a RPI3b (as other Apps have done before.... never ran into this?!)

```
var gpioController = GpioController.GetDefault();
// gpio controller is null ... why?!
ServiceContainer.Instance.Register(new IO(gpioController));;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. It was in Windows IoT configuration itself. There is a "default controller driver" in the devices tab. It was set to a DMA driver. Changing it to "Inbox driver" and rebooting the Pi solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the DMA driver which offers better performances, you need to activate/declare it to the API before querying the `GpioControleler`

```
// This needs the following capabilities
// <iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices" />
// <DeviceCapability Name="109b86ad-f53d-4b76-aa5f-821e2ddf2141"/>
if (LightningProvider.IsLightningEnabled)
{
    LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();
}

var gpioController = GpioController.GetDefault();
// gpioController is valid
```

See [Lightning Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/lightningproviders)
 for more details